# How to remove page flipping effect in beamer?

Tags: beamer, mac, viewers

I have a feeling that my `beamer` slides are set so that whenever I flip a page in osx's PREVIEW, there is a page flip effect. Right now I suspect it is either PREVIEW itself (the viewing software) or the actual slides.

Is there a way to verify it, and if it is indeed something the `.tex` file, is there a way to remove that effect?

The reason I suspect it might be the slides themselves (and not PREVIEW) is because this page flipping effect does not happen with other PDF files.

EDIT:

The following is a MWE that does the page flipping (for Mac OSx with TexLive 2012 using PREVIEW).

```
\documentclass[sansserif,mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, epsfig, xspace}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage[normal,tight,center]{subfigure}
\setlength{\subfigcapskip}{-.5em}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1ex}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}{list}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, what version of the OS and Preview are you using? I can't replicate this effect with Preview in OS 10.6 or 10.7. Is is possible that Preview in OS 10.8 has some new preferences?

Comment: Open the document using another viewer (Skim, Adobe) and see if the effect is replicated. Also, did you try both "Slideshow" and "Full Screen" options? When I open in "Full Screen" there is an effect, and this doesn't happen in the "Slideshow" version.

Comment: @Vivi I think you should post this as an answer. The "Full Screen" option only appeared in Lion so you might want to mention that too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this type of problem the first step should be to open the document using another viewer, such as [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) or [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/), to see if the problem is replicated. Of course, this may not always be possible if you don't have access to them, but since they are free software, it is always a good idea to have more than one viewer installed.

Within Preview itself you should try both "Full Screen" and "Slideshow" ways of viewing your pdf in presentation mode. While the Slideshow option does not include any transition effects, the more recent Full Screen option, which appeared since the Lion release, includes a transition effect which is likely what you are referring to.

Comment: the problem was indeed Full screen vs. Slideshow.